# Unable to call function via HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to call a function via a submit button, but I am unable to submit it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>API Call</h2>

<form method="post" action="display()">
  <label for="gid">Global Device ID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="gid" name="gid" value="m99002021" readonly><br>
  <label for="type">Type:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="type" name="type" value="EVNT" readonly><br><br>
  <label for="start">Start Date Time:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="start" name="start" value="2020-09-01 00:00:00" readonly><br><br>
  <label for="end">End Date Time:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="end" name="end" value="2020-09-30 23:59:59" readonly><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Execute">
</form> 

<?php
function display()
{
  echo "hello".$_POST["gid"]."<br>";
  echo "hello".$_POST["type"]."<br>";
  echo "hello".$_POST["start"]."<br>";
  echo "hello".$_POST["end"]."<br>";
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
       display();
} 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

When clicking on the `execute` button I am getting bellow page

[image]

The URL is `file:///C:/Users/Faisal/Desktop/display()`

**Update 1**

I have used `xampp` for my webserver. Now I am trying to access it via `http://localhost/udil/backend/main.php` and it gives me bellow page

[image]

when I click on the `execute` button I am getting below the page

[image]

How can I properly submit it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are mixing PHP and JavaScript the wrong way. And you don't use a webserver with PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I execute a PHP function in a form action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595358/how-can-i-execute-a-php-function-in-a-form-action)

Comment: @yunzen I have tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328392/6854117) solution?

Comment: @Moeez At first you need a webserver running PHP. Without the webserver, using PHP doesn't make sense

Comment: @yunzen can I use xampp for it?

Comment: XAMPP is an option. But try DDEV, if you are willing to install docker and docker-compose on your computer

Comment: @yunzen using xampp still gives me same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are now using XAMPP to use PHP, we can start working on your misconception.

In your code you have this line
`<form method="post" action="display()">`

It seems as if you were thinking that the action is the JavaScript action to be called. But that is not the case.

The `action` of a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes_for_form_submission) does not call JavaScript, but it sends the form with all the form data to the URL given in this attribute. Since there is the value of `display()` in your `action` attribute, the Browser tries to send the data to the address `display()` relative to your form URL. But this is an address the webserver has no answer to and thus sends back an 404 error.

The question for you that I have now is: what should happen after the form was sent? Should the form data just be written to the document? I assume that is what you want to achieve. If yes, try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>API Call</h2>

<?php // Omit the action of the form. 
      // Now your PHP script will be called again, when the form is submitted
?>
<form method="post">
  <label for="gid">Global Device ID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="gid" name="gid" value="m99002021" readonly><br>
  <label for="type">Type:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="type" name="type" value="EVNT" readonly><br><br>
  <label for="start">Start Date Time:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="start" name="start" value="2020-09-01 00:00:00" readonly><br><br>
  <label for="end">End Date Time:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="end" name="end" value="2020-09-30 23:59:59" readonly><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Execute">
</form> 

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
  echo "hello".$_POST["gid"]."<br>";
  echo "hello".$_POST["type"]."<br>";
  echo "hello".$_POST["start"]."<br>";
  echo "hello".$_POST["end"]."<br>";
} 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

No JavaScript is involved in this code, because you don't need it.

BTW. This code should be in a PHP file, not an HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the display() from form and click the Execute button. It will properly work

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>API Call</h2>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <label for="gid">Global Device ID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="gid" name="gid" value="m99002021" readonly><br>
  <label for="type">Type:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="type" name="type" value="EVNT" readonly><br><br>
  <label for="start">Start Date Time:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="start" name="start" value="2020-09-01 00:00:00" readonly><br><br>
  <label for="end">End Date Time:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="end" name="end" value="2020-09-30 23:59:59" readonly><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Execute">
</form> 

<?php
function display()
{
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])
  {
    echo "hello".$_POST["gid"]."<br>";
    echo "hello".$_POST["type"]."<br>";
    echo "hello".$_POST["start"]."<br>";
    echo "hello".$_POST["end"]."<br>";
  }
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
       display();
} 

?>

</body>
</html>
```